# Cannot use an attached property in my DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, attached-properties

I am relatively new to WPF and am trying to understand Attached Properties to use them in my test application I am using  as a learning base. The AP is in it'own source file named AP.cs that lives in namespace `WPFPages.ViewModels`.

So I have created a simple AP as shown below that stores an `int` value.

```
public class AP: DependencyObject
{
    public static int Gettest ( DependencyObject obj )
    {
       return ( int ) obj . GetValue ( testProperty );
    }

    public static void Settest ( DependencyObject obj, int value )
    {
       obj . SetValue ( testProperty, value );
    }
    
    public static readonly DependencyProperty testProperty =
        DependencyProperty . RegisterAttached ( "test", typeof ( int ), typeof ( AP ), new PropertyMetadata ( 2 ), Ontestchanged);

    private static bool Ontestchanged ( object value )
    {
            Console . WriteLine ($"test value changed to {value}");
            return true;
    }
}
```

In my XAML I have set the value using `models:AP.test="21"` which works as expected, verfied by my `WriteLine` debug in the AP.

However, I want to have this value as a column in a `ListBox`, and therefore have a `DataTemplate` that has the following entry:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tst" 
           Text="{Binding Path=(models:AP.test), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
           Width="55"/>
```

Sadly, I only see the default set in the AP in my `ListBox`, NOT the value of `21`. I have set it to in my `ListBox` properties. I have declared the namespace in my XAML files as shown below.

```
xmlns:models="clr-namespace:WPFPages.ViewModels"
```

I have read every possible article on attached properties, and have tried more variations on a theme in terms of syntax to make this work, but with no success at all. So far I have spent 3 days trying to get this simple AP to work.

I feel sure it is something simple due to my inexperience with the complexities of `Binding`, but would greatly appreciate some assistance in getting to the bottom of how I make this work, as I can see how powerful the AP's can be, if only I can make them work of course?.

UPDATE instead of using Comment :

```
<ListBox x:Name="listboxclass"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource lvItemStyle1}"
    BorderThickness="2"
    BorderBrush="{StaticResource Blue0}"
    FontWeight="Normal"
    FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,0,164"   >
    <ListBoxItem
          Height="45"
          models:AP.test="21"/>
```

The relevant `Style` code is:

Hope  this clarifies it.  I am happy to get the same value appearing in the column selected for now.

```
<Style x:Key="lvItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding (models:AP.Background)}"/>-->

    <Setter Property="Template">

          <Setter.Value>
                
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                      <Grid>
                            <!--<Border x:Name="Bd" 
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                  <Border.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="borderbckgrnd" Color="{TemplateBinding models:AP.Background}" />
                                  </Border.Background>

                                  <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentpresenter"                                                            
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                  </ContentPresenter>



                            </Border>-->

                            <!--I have tried ALL of these & they ALL cause Exceptions on loading
                                  "{Binding models:AP.test}"
                                  "{Binding Path=(models:AP.test)}"
                                  "{Binding (models:AP.test)}"
                                  "{Binding Source=models:AP.test}"
                                  "{TemplateBinding  models:AP.test}"-->
                            <Border x:Name="Bd" >
                                  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerId}" 
                                             Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=NwCustomerDataTemplateBorder1}"  
                                             Width="50" 
                                             Padding="1" 
                                              x:Name="CustomerId"/>
                                        
                                        <!--NB Output window shows :
                                              AP : test value changed to 2
                                              AP : test value changed to 21
                                                    so it is definitely being set.
                                        but the field is empty in the list when run-->
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="tst" 
                                             Text="{Binding Path=models:Attach.test}"
                                              Foreground="Red"                                                           
                                             Width="55"/>
                                        <!--this does  not give error, but does not work either
                                        Height="{Binding Path=models:AP.test, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"-->
                                        
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CompanyName}" Width="165" Padding="1" x:Name="CompanyName"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContactName}" Width="135" Padding="1" x:Name="ContactName"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContactTitle}" Width="40" Padding="1"  x:Name="ContactTitle"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" Width="150" Padding="1"  x:Name="Address"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding City }" Width="80" Padding="1"  x:Name="City"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PostalCode}" Width="75" Padding="1"  x:Name="PostalCode"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" Width="75" Padding="1"  x:Name="Country"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Phone}" Width="95" Padding="1"  x:Name="Phone"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Fax}" Width="95" Padding="1"  x:Name="Fax"/>
                                  </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: On which element did you set `models:AP.test="21"`? Should it be set differently for each list box item or is it the same value for all items? You wrote that you want a column in a `ListBox`, so do you use a `GridView` with it or what do you mean by that?

Comment: As a note, a class that declares only attached properties does not need to be derived from DependencyObject. All declarations in that class are static.

Comment: `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` means you would have set the attached property on the TextBlock named `tst` in the DataTemplate. How have you done that?

Comment: To Clarify, my Listbox declaration is :-

Comment: Ooops
               <ListBox x:Name="listboxclass"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource lvItemStyle1}"
                  BorderThickness="2"
                  BorderBrush="{StaticResource Blue0}"
                  FontWeight="Normal"
                  FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,0,164"   >
                  <ListBoxItem
                        Height="45"
                        models:AP.test="21"/>

Comment: I a having real problems trying to add code into the Comment field on the web site !
          <ListBox x:Name="listboxclass"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource lvItemStyle1}"
                  BorderThickness="2"
                  BorderBrush="{StaticResource Blue0}"
                  FontWeight="Normal"
                  FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,0,164"   >
                  <ListBoxItem
                        Height="45"
                        models:AP.test="21"/>

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could bind to the attached property of the parent `ListBox` in the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListBox models:AP.test="21">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tst" 
                       Text="{Binding Path=(models:AP.test), 
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" 
                       Width="55"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, you have (finally) clarified it in my mind, and I am getting the correct values in my listbox now -  Thanks to both of you for your patience with me

Comment: I must be getting too old as I cannot seem to find any way to Accept or Vote or Upvote on the Page.  Can you tell me how exactly do I do that and I will do so with pleasure ??

Comment: Did you see the link in my previous comment? Please check it out.

Comment: Yes indeed, you both put your fingers on the problem !  Can you tell me how to Upvote as per my previous message?

Comment: I do not have any such arrow on my screen.  I think I am going mad, it must be so simple.  I cannot paste a screen grab to show you my screen but it has  the Stack Overflow info column at the left and then the questions answers text, but no images or anything else between the two except for a smallish digit "0" to the left of my original question ?  I am really sorry for being so difficult, but I really want to "conform?" and do the upvoting etc

Answer (score 0):

The attached `AP.test` property is defined on the `ListBoxItem`, so you need to refer to that element in order to get the assigned value, otherwise the binding will not work. Your trials do not  work because:

- `{Binding models:AP.test}` - This is not the correct syntax for binding attached properties, use parentheses `(` and `)`, see [binding path syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0#binding-path-syntax).
- `{Binding Path=(models:AP.test)}` - Correct syntax, but the attached property will be resolved on the element itself, here the `TextBlock`, which does not define it.
- `{Binding (models:AP.test)}` - Same as above.
- `{Binding Source=models:AP.test}` - Sets the attached property as binding source, which is wrong.
- `{TemplateBinding  models:AP.test}` - Does not work with attached properties.

You can make the binding work by using the attached property binding syntax and refering to the `ListBoxItem` that defines the value. Since the `TextBlock` is part of the `ListBoxItem` template, you can use a `RelativeSource` binding with [`TemplateParent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource.templatedparent?view=net-5.0).

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tst"
           Text="{Binding (local:AP.test), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
           Foreground="Red"
           Width="55" />
```

Alternatively, you can specify the [`AncestorType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource.ancestortype?view=net-5.0), as `ListBoxItem` is a parent of a `ListBoxItem`.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tst"
           Text="{Binding (models:AP.test), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
           Foreground="Red"
           Width="55" />
```

Comment: Many thanks for this detailed and complete clarification of my errors, AND the correct syntax that has worked perfectly for my feeble attempt at writing wpf code.  I will now go off and spend some time experimenting further into this convoluted world of WPF binding.  Thanks to you and indeed mm8 who also provided the same solution. Much appreciated

Comment: @IanTurner Please note, that this solution works for binding the attached property set on a `ListBoxItem`, not `ListBox` itself, that is the difference. Furthermore, the template binding only works in a `ControlTemplate`, not a `DataTemplate`. Both answers are for different use-cases.

Comment: Comments duly  noted !  Maybe that explains one of the items below, but not the other ?  One more slight problem after experimentation.
I have a TextBlocks in a ListBox DataTemplate accessing the AP.test field, but when run, I get the Default value (32767)  of the AP, not the value (21) it is actually set to in my xaml code, which does show as set in the Output Window.  :-

Text="{Binding (models:AP.test), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"

I have Tried just Listbox as well, same result.